# How can I transform 5 VDC from a powerbank into 60 VAC?

Tags: transformer

How can I transform the voltage of 5 VDC from a powerbank into 60 VAC?

- Input 5 VDC from a powerbank.
- Output 60 VAC (60HZ), my end-component is consuming 0.3 W.

Which components do I need to use? I could not find any finished product. Is this 60 VAC dangerous?

Comment: Hi. Three questions: 1. Using what is called an "inverter", and you should really have found that when looking for "battery to AC". 2. All the components necessary to build an inverter that has the specs you need, which you've not given us aside from the voltage (but you can also buy inverters). 3. Yes, it is.

Comment: So all in all, this is too broad; you're asking this as if you've not researched this, which either means you didn't actually research this, or this project is a bit too large for your current state, and you need to learn about power electronics basics, first. In both cases, no answer that we could write here would be enough.

Comment: The solution you choose also depends on how much power you want, at what frequency, and only you have a clue about that so far.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am new into this topic, I should read more, you are right. I updated my question, my end device needs 0.31185watt

Comment: @Suisse: I tidied up the post a little. You can round that to 0.3 W. No booster is going to be that precise. What is it that requires 60 V AC? What frequency?

Comment: @Transistor I am trying to work with smart glass. It has a power supplier which transforms 230 VAC into 60 VAC. And I was asking myself if I could actually use a power bank to make it mobile.

Comment: what is smart glass? How do you know that's 60 V at 60 Hz?

Comment: @MarcusMüller since your name sounds german, I assume you understand german, and it is ok that I send you the datenblatt which is only available in german: https://www.ifoha.de/shop/media/pdf/12/c7/f4/_datenblatt-cleverfilm-weiss.pdf

Comment: Hm, that doesn't say anything about 60 Hz. Where does that come from?

Comment: actually from another company, which has all the same specs (same product) and that detail with 60HZ more.. which is not on that link above.. but it was written somewhere - is it really that important? :'D

Comment: yes, otherwise Brian and I wouldn't be asking about it

Comment: Does the 60 Hz output *have* to be a sinewave?

Comment: no - but it would be nice if yes.

Comment: There are a variety of light/display technologies which need a moderate AC voltage often supplied from a dedicated inverter - eg, EL backlights (common before the recent shift to LED backlights), nixie tubes, EL wire, etc.  Narrow down the specs of exactly what you need, and search for solutions to that sort of problem.  A *product* would probably not first convert the battery voltage to 5v, but rather directly to the target AC voltage.

Comment: Just tap directly into the battery and use a step up converter, then invert

Comment: An Power Supply constructed to conform to the PELV rules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage can be considered safe at 60V. Note, even as 120V DC is defined safe in general, 60V is an upper bound in a lot of applications (I have learned the value of 60V at work...) So if you are not trained in electrics/electronics, consider 60V is Your! upper bound.